# Execute Oracle function from PowerBuilder

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, call, powerbuilder

I have an Oracle function with one argument. I need to call it from PowerBuilder. Is this possible? If so, how? Thanks!

My function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OPEN.F_VALIDATION (f_date DATE)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
v_an number;
v_debug_line varchar2(20);
BEGIN
/*some relevant code - delete, selects, updates, inserts*/

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('OK');
   COMMIT;
   RETURN v_an;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('v_debug_line: ' || v_debug_line);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'ERROR: ' || SQLERRM);
      ROLLBACK;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ERROR');
      RETURN v_an;
END F_VALIDATION ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to call an Oracle function in PowerBuilder, assuming your app is already connected to the database:

```
long l_rc
date d_date = today()

SELECT open.f_validation( :d_date )
INTO :l_rc
FROM dual;

if sqlca.sqlcode <> 0 then
    messagebox( "Exception", "Unable to validate:~r~n" + sqlca.sqlerrtext )
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to call an Oracle function from PowerBuilder - Google knows, for example on [PowerBuilder: Calling Oracle Stored Procedures and Functions](https://www.appeon.com/developers/get-help/knowledgebase/powerbuilder-calling-oracle-stored-procedures-and-functions.html), saying that

> ... a good approach is to first declare it as an external function and
>   then invoke it based on that declaration.

I don't feel like copy/pasting that contents over here because it'll most probably be wrong (as I said, I don't use that software product).

However, I have some objections on code you posted. I apologize if it goes off-topic.

"Some relevant code" - this won't work *just like that*; what DML (and why) do you perform in that function?

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return number
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    insert into dept (deptno, dname) values (99, 'test');
  6    return 1;
  7  end;
  8  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test from dual;
select f_test from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.F_TEST", line 5
```

If you want to perform DML in a function, you miss the PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION and COMMIT the DML (though, COMMIT is there already so maybe there's the pragma ass well), but that's most probably NOT a good idea.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  5  begin
  6    insert into dept (deptno, dname) values (99, 'test');
  7    commit;
  8    return 1;
  9  end;
 10  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test from dual;

    F_TEST
----------
         1

SQL>
```

[AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5027643800346194460) says that such things are *evil*, so - consider using a procedure with an OUT parameter instead.

Also, you do realize that such an EXCEPTION handler is of no use for end users? They can't ever see DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE result. On the other hand, seeing "v_debug_line" suggests that you use it for debugging purposes - in that case, I have no objections on that.

But really, try not to use DML in a function.

Once again, sorry if it is irrelevant & you insist on keeping it the way it is.

Comment: Should this be a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: Yes. If Stackoverflow ever changes 600-character restriction & enables nice formatting, I'll gladly convert it to a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, the Oracle function is declared in the same schema as the application connects.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_VALIDATION(f_date DATE) RETURN NUMBER IS
  v_an number;
begin

  /* If f_date is today then 1 else 0 */
  select decode(to_date(sysdate), f_date, 1, 0) into v_an from dual;
  RETURN v_an;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    /* This will never happen */
    v_an := -1;
    RETURN v_an;
END F_VALIDATION;
```

To declare stored procedures as external functions for the user object:

- In the Script view in the User Object painter, select [Declare] from the first list and Local External Functions from the second list.
- Place your cursor in the Declare Local External Functions view.
  From the pop-up menu or the Edit menu, select Paste Special>SQL>Remote Stored Procedures.
- PowerBuilder loads the stored procedures from your database and displays the Remote Stored Procedures dialog box.
- Select the names of one or more stored procedures that you want to declare as functions for the user object, and click OK.
- PowerBuilder retrieves the stored procedure declarations from the database and pastes each declaration into the view.
- For example, here is the declaration that displays on one line when you select F_VALIDATION:

  > function double F_VALIDATION(datetime F_DATE) RPCFUNC ALIAS FOR "F_VALIDATION"

Assumptions:

- Your SQLCA is connected to the same schema where F_VALIDATION was compiled.
- The PowerBuilder code exists from the object where you declared F_VALIDATION.

Here is an example of how to call the function.

```
double ld_result
ad_date = datetime( today(), now() )

ld_result = F_VALIDATION( ad_date )

if sqlca.sqlcode = -1 then
    //Some error handling
    //messagebox("Unexpected error", "Error calling F_VALIDATION. database error message=" + sqlca.sqlerrtext )
    ld_result = -1
end if
```